# UIsing Multer and GridFsStorage, upload.Sing('file") req.file is still undefined (Not using Postman)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to store a image in Mongodb using multer, grid-fs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage. I am not using Postman while developing this. I am using a database directly off Mongodb. When console logging the output of req.file the console display undefined as shown below:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const multer = require('multer')
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream')

 // create storage object

          let storage = new GridFsStorage({
              url: dbURI,
              file: (req, file) => {
                  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                          if(err){
                              console.log(err)
                              reject(err)
                          }

                             const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
                                const fileInfo = {
                                    filename: filename,
                                    bucketName: 'avatar'
                                };
                              resolve(fileInfo);
                      })
                  })
              }
          })

const upload = multer({ storage });

 
app.post('/uploadProfile', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  res.json({file: req.file})
})
```

Here is what my form on the client side looks like:

```
  <form action="/uploadProfile" id="profileImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                   
        <input type="file" name="file" id="profilePictureFile" onchange="readURL()">
                          
    </form>
```

I am not using a submit button inside of the form. I have other configuations the client must do before submitting. This form is just to store the file. Once the configuration on the client side is done a Javascript funtion will submit the form using the forms id.

This is what I get through the post when I use req.body:

```
{
  file: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 899575,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Wade\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_f7575362f5542945c417a0e7f3457c28',
    name: 'IMG_1474.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2023-06-21T03:00:02.353Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      fd: null,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\Wade\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_f7575362f5542945c417a0e7f3457c28',
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 899575,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

I know the file is getting sent but for some reason there is a error and multer is not working correctly. Is there something that I am missing or doing wrong?

I have tried looking for answers on the internet but all of them seem to be different to how I have it set up. Again I an not using postman but submitting them directly to Mongodb. I'm sure that shouldn't be the problem because I will have to launch this site using Mongodb anyways.